# Attempting to restore a different version (?) of Computer Modern

Tags: fonts, pdftex, computer-modern, latin-modern

I am compiling a document on a different machine. Despite my best efforts, the fonts show differences and therefore the compiled documents don't turn out identically:

First document:

[image: First document]

---

Second document:

[image: New document]

Note the serifs, for example.

The machine I originally wrote the document on is not currently available. I use Miktex + Texmaker on both machines. According to the PDF properties, the first document was compiled with pdfTeX 1.40.24 and the new one on .25. I struggle to understand this discrepancy and how to fix it, if there is anything to fix.

I am not using any font package specification - it's just [T1]{fontenc}.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a real difference. Check the fonts with pdffonts or with adobe reader. And check if you have cm-super installed on the new machine.

Comment: hard to tell from an image but the lighter one is probably using type3 fonts, install cm-super

Comment: I have cm-super installed. And to me there is an obvious difference in the weight of the serifs. The d in Introduction doesn't have its serifs in the same place even.

Comment: I wonder why you are using Computer Modern, compiling with pdflatex. A more up-do-date approach would be to compile with lualatex, which uses Latin Modern Roman (similar to cm) as default OpenType font. Then you do not need to worry about encoding (always utf-8) and the small caps are in the same font.

Comment: I suppose "legacy template" is the best way to say this. Either way, I should do everything within my power to replicate the original style.

Comment: There are very many reasons to use pdfLaTeX. If the question concerned difficulties typesetting Arabic or Japanese, wondering would be an obvious move. But I doubt there's any reason to think there'd be no discrepancies if LuaTeX was used rather than pdfTeX. If anything, I'd suspect the opposite because there are more likely to be changes.

Comment: Post the output of `pdffonts` on each document if you don't know what to make of it.

Comment: Why do you want the versions to look exactly identical? They both look ok to me, even if they are not 100% the same.